# Usar os dados de uma request em uma variavel global

Tags: javascript, json, api, variáveis, request

Estou com uma dificuldade que tenho certeza que é simples para vocês!

```
var request = require('request')
var a
var b

request('https://exrates.me/openapi/v1/public/ticker?currency_pair=eth_usd', function (error, response, body) {

    a = JSON.parse(body)
    b = tickerEx1[0]['name']
    console.log(b) // funciona perfeitamente

})

console.log(b) // nao funciona
```

Nao consigo usar a variavel b fora do request.
Já tentei declarar a variavel fora, usar return... nada.

Comment: Provavelmente tem algum erro dentro do request, se estiver usando algo de Ajax, utilize console de desenvolvedor do navegador, isso pode te ajudar. Aproveite e desligue o cache do navegador.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na realidade o que acontece é que, como a variável é preenchida dentro do `callback`, que é assíncrono, quando o `console.log` é alcançado a variável ainda não foi preenchida.

Caso você queira executar o `console.log` apenas depois da execução da requisição, você pode transformá-la em uma promessa e executar apenas após o resolução da mesma.

```
const { get } = require('request');

const { promisify } = require('util');

// Transforma o "get" em uma função que retorna uma promessa
const promisedGET = promisify(get);

const visitar = async uri => {
  const { statusCode, body } = await promisedGET({ uri });

  // Retorna um erro caso o status seja diferente de 200
  if (statusCode !== 200) throw new Error(body);

  return { body };
}

(async () => {
  // Inicia o timer
  console.time('Execução');
  try {
    const { body } = await visitar('https://exrates.me/openapi/v1/public/ticker?currency_pair=eth_usd');

    const a = JSON.parse(body);
    const b = a[0]['name'];

    console.log(b);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }

  // Totaliza o tempo de execução
  console.timeEnd('Execução');
})();
```